# how to use logback configured via logback.groovy with groovy

Tags: groovy, logback

I am not able to use logback configured via logback.groovy with groovy.

If in a directory i have a script file called for example FooBar.groovy and the file logback.groovy
when i run  `groovy FooBar.groovy`   groovy tries to compiles the logback configuration file too and my script doesn't work, i have to fallback to the default xml configuration file for logback (logback.xml).

How can i make this to works?   can i call `groovy somefiles.groovy`  and configure groovy to ignore logback.groovy?

Thanks for the help

Comment: How could it be script does not work? Explain the reason. I think the right solution would be to make your script working, not fallback to .xml config.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reason for your problems is that the logback configuration file should never be compiled. It is read at runtime from LogBack via `GroovyShell` or a similar mechanism.

The solution depends on your project setup. Following you will find a solution for a project build with [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/) following the Maven [Standard Directory Layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html):

First file is `src/main/groovy/Test.groovy`:

```groovy
import org.slf4j.Logger
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

class Test {
    static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Test.class)

    static void main(String[] args) {
        LOG.debug("Test")
    }
}
```

Second file is `src/main/resources/logback.groovy`:

```groovy
import static ch.qos.logback.classic.Level.INFO
import static ch.qos.logback.classic.Level.DEBUG

import ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder
import ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender

appender("CONSOLE", ConsoleAppender) {
  encoder(PatternLayoutEncoder) {
    pattern = "%-4relative [%thread] - %msg%n"
  }
}
root(DEBUG, ["CONSOLE"])
```

I omitted the Gradle build file (`build.gradle`).

The standard directory layout guarantees that every file in `src/main/groovy` is compiled, while everything in `src/main/resources` is included in the class path. So LogBack is able to find that file at runtime.

**Update**: Didn't read your problem carefully enough. I could not manage to solve the problem when both files are in the same directory and I start it via `groovy Test.groovy`. I think this is not possible. The groovy command always compiles all groovy files in the current directory and in the given classpath.

Comment: I think you right, it's not possible to manage this situation when both files are in the same directory, I mark your question as accepted because the first part describes a right way to use groovy and a logback configuration's file in groovy dsl.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in an Eclipse Greclipse environment (and came to this question as best problem reference via Google). It will be easily adaptable to other Groovy environments as well and the basic principles/setup will hold true.

Here is what needs to be done/ensured:

**`Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path`** ...

- `-> Source -> Add Folder` or check properly already set up

  - all relevant files must be in the `Included` (e.g. `(All)`) and not in the `Excluded` (e.g. `(None)`) patterns
  - **`src/main/groovy/`** (should contain your Groovy classes)
  - **`src/test/resources/`** (where `logback.groovy` is directly underneath)
- make sure that under `-> Output Folders` the `src/main/resources` is before `src/test/resources` so the right `logback.groovy` (if you have one for test as well) is taken in the normal run

**`Project -> Properties -> Groovy Compiler -> Groovy Script Folders`** ...

- **`[ ] src/main/groovy/**/*.groovy`** (or similar pattern for your classes must be unchecked)
- **`[x] src/main/resources/**/*.groovy`** (or similar pattern for your normal `logback.groovy` must be checked)
- **`[x] src/test/resources/**/*.groovy`** (or similar pattern for your test `logback.groovy` must be checked)

test and normal `logback.groovy` [should work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24919167/1915920) this way.

As a result you should see the following copied from the source resource to the target folders:

- `target/classes/logback.groovy`
- `target/test-classes/logback.groovy`

side note: Furthermore, if you are using Groovy inside ANT in Eclipse, all you have to do is `Windows -> Preferences -> Ant -> Runtime -> Classpath -> Ant Home Entries -> Add Variable... -> ${project_classpath}` and `logback.groovy` will also be applied properly :).
(Since the `${project_classpath}` does not seem to (always) export in the above order, we had to manually `Add Folder -> target/classes` and move above the other to make it work with the right `logback.groovy`)