# logback: how do I differentiate logging between test and main when using groovy configuration?

Tags: java, groovy, logback

I understand that, when using xml configuration, you can put a `logback-test.xml` under `src/test/resources` for test phase logging and `logback.xml` under `src/main/resources` for main logging.

However, how can I achieve the same thing for groovy configuration? Thank you very much.

Comment: Basically this should work exactly the same. Do You use any build tool?

Comment: How do you mean? Put a logback-test.groovy under src/test/resources and logback.groovy under src/main/resources? I use gradle for build.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Or leave *.xml files there.

Comment: -@Opal: No, that's not true. I tested it with one logback.groovy under src/main/resources and one logback-test.groovy under src/test/resources. It turns out that the configurations in logback-test.groovy did not take effect.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to put your `logback.groovy` log configuration for your tests  under `/src/test/resources`. It'll take precedence over the `logback.groovy` under `/src/main/resources`

Comment: I can confirm this :-)