# When/how often does logback.groovy get reloaded in local grails 3?

Tags: grails, logback

In Grails 3.x, how often does the logback.groovy file get reloaded and applied when running locally with `grails run-app`?

I do see messages like the following when I make changes to the file, but it doesn't seem that those changes are taking effect. I also [read that the logback.groovy file is not supposed to be compiled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14961608/539048).

```
File C:\eclipse_ws\my-app\grails-app\conf\logback.groovy changed, recompiling...
```

In my logback.groovy file, I also have [`scan()`](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/groovy.html) at the bottom, but that doesn't seem to make any difference either.

```
if (Environment.isDevelopmentMode()) {
    scan() // need this or does grails do it automatically?
}
```

I was unable to find any information on this in the grails or logback documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation [here](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/groovy.html), it looks like logback by default checks the file for changes every minute.  And you can change it by passing in a string to scan like scan("30 seconds"), for ex.

The reason you are not seeing the changes is because on startup, the application compiles that file and puts it under build/resources/main/logback.groovy.  When you edit the conf/logback.groovy file, it does not update that file, so the changes are not seen.  However if you edit THAT file directly, you'll see the changes (within a minute).

**Side note:**
I like an external logging config file so I put the following in application.yml

```
logging:
    config: 'C:\log\logback.groovy'
```

and just update that file to pick up changes.

Comment: Wow it's disappointing that Grails didn't account for this and auto-update the real runtime file (build/resources/main/logback.groovy) when you change the source in conf/.